# What are the keycaps of the A1016 keyboard made from?

Tags: keyboard

I loved the *Apple A1016* bluetooth keyboard. It's a shame Apple don't make this any more. In particular the key caps were made out of a slightly soft matte-finished material that felt very nice to type on.

Can anyone tell me what this material is?

I'm partly asking so that I might find a similar 3rd party keyboard - suggestions welcome. I did try a *Ducky DK2108 Zero* but it was noisy with hard plastic key caps and not really what I was after.

Comment: Alternatively the A1048 was the same model but with cable.  There are quite a bit of both of these available on eBay, including 'new old stock'  Also look for M9270LL/A (A1016) and M9034LL/A (A1048) these are the same models.

Comment: You could try to find a used A1016 keyboard on eBay. There's probably even some new-in-box.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have seen the new old stock on Amazon etc. but couldn't help thinking it must be counterfeit (they stopped making them in 2007!?) I may consider them. I'd still like to know what the key caps are made from though since I may like to buy a third party keyboard.

Comment: I still want to know!